# возврат jquery callback теряет данные

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

приветствую всех, в этот не трудовой день

Хотел спарсить JSON с определенного файла на хостинге, в переменную, начал с вывода в консоль. Пробую отобразить данные страницы в консоле

```
//1. с чего я начал
var urlparse = 'http://mysite.ru/file.txt';
$.ajax({
  url: urlparse,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

в консоле ошибка, нужен callback.. ошибка - мой URL+?callback=jQuery191050...

```
//2. пробуем, но уже с коллбэком
function meCallback(urlparse, callback) {  
$.ajax({
  url: urlparse,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
     callback(data);
  }
});
}  

var urlparse = 'http://mysite.ru/file.txt';
meCallback(urlparse, function(data) {  
    console.log(data);
});
```

вылетело: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.. сам пробовал менять dataType, но тогда сыпятся другие ошибки

Господа, объясните, как правильно считать данные файла с хостинге?

p.s. там на странице, что то на подобии: {"1111":{"буквы":"1111"},"1112":{"буквы":"1112"}}

---

upd: ошибка такая - при jsonp, в консоле красная строка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : file.txt?callback=jQuery1910290…_1479647887056&_=1479647887057:1
```

Comment: добавь в вопрос полный текст ошибок

Comment: добавил. ест-но. если из браузера зайти на эту страницу ( текстовый файл ) , все отображается